# Cannot create bookdown custom template's format function

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, bookdown

I am trying to create a [custom template](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/templates.html) for a PDF book in [bookdown](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown), this custom template is necessary because:

- I need to use a custom latex template consisting in more files (`.cls`, `.sty` and so on).

#### Package

I have so created a new package:

```
mytemplate/
|-- DESCRIPTION
|-- inst
|   |-- rmarkdown
|   |   |-- templates
|   |   |   |-- book_tex
|   |   |   |   |-- resources
|   |   |   |   |   |-- template.tex
|   |   |   |   |-- skeleton
|   |   |   |   |   |-- skeleton.Rmd
|   |   |   |   |   |-- svmono.cls
|   |   |   |   |   |-- biblio.bib
|   |   |   |   |-- template.yaml
|-- man
|   |-- book_tex.Rd
|-- R
|   |-- book_tex.R
```

As you can see, my template needs some files to be deployed, it is not just one single `.tex` file. So I need to make sure all those files are copied in the output dir before processing. I have created a custom format:

```r
#' Personal book.
#'
#' This format was adapted from the Springer manuscript package for Springer
#' monographs.
#'
#' @inheritParams bookdown::pdf_book
#' @param ... Arguments to \code{bookdown::pdf_book}
#' @return R Markdown output format to pass to \code{\link[bookdown::render_book]{render_book}}
#'
#' @export
book_tex <- function(..., keep_tex = TRUE, citation_package = 'none') {
  # locations of resource files in the package
  pkg_resource = function(...) {
    system.file(..., package = "librarstemplates")
  }

  tmpl = pkg_resource("rmarkdown", "templates", "book_tex", "resources", "template.tex")
  if (tmpl == "") {
    stop("Couldn't find pkg resource template")
  }

  bookdown::pdf_book(..., base_format = rmarkdown::pdf_document, template = tmpl, keep_tex = TRUE)
}
```

#### Running

I have created ax example book `example.Rmd` using this template:

```
---
title: Title here
subtitle: Do you have a subtitle? If so, write it here

output: mytemplate::book_tex
---

# Introduction
Your text comes here.
```

I installed the package via `devtools::install()` and then, in a different R session (in a folder containing `example.Rmd`), I run:

```r
bookdown::render_book("example.Rmd")
```

#### Problem

This is not copying all the files because, when compiling the tex file after replacing the placeholders in the template, the tex compiler complains that the `.cls` file cannot be found.

The problem is that I have not really understood how to write a custom format. What return type does it expect? I can see that `rmarkdown::render` will invoke the format function at a certain point. So what is the procedure to get my files deployed?

#### Troubleshooting

I think that in my custom format, I need to take care of the deploying. I have seen that `rmarkdown::draft` is what I need to invoke. But it requires the file name which I do not know how to get :(

In [`rmarkdown::render`](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/render.R), I can see:

```r
output_format <- create_output_format(output_format$name,
                                      output_format$options)
```

The `input` is not passed, I do not have the information, in my custom format, so I cannot call `rmarkdown::draft` to deploy the files.

---

#### Edit

It seems like I have misunderstood the purpose of the `draft` function. I thought it was used to copy the resources, actually it will create a draft, meaning it will use the file named `skeleton` to create an initial draft. I think that in my custom format function I will need to duplicate the logic for moving all resources in the new directory where the book will be created.

**Question** Is there a function I can use to move all the resources or do I need to do this manually?